# Product descriptions without definite / indefinite articles

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, headlinese

I have read a review on Amazon and most products descriptions are written without definite / indefinite articles. Does it happen because of headlinese?

For instance, this is a part of the product description for baby bottles:

> Safe in microwave, boiling water, dishwashers and sterilizers
>
> Nipple and body is made of 100% safe hygienic silicone

I would wrote:

> Safe in a microwave, boiling water, dishwashers and sterilizers
>
> The Nipple and the body is made of 100% safe hygienic silicone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an abbreviated style used in advertisements.

> 1 **Abbreviated Styles**
>
> Some styles of writing and speech have their own special grammar rules, often because of the need to save space or time.
>
> 1. Advertisements and instructions
>
>    - Small ads and instructions **often leave out articles**, subject or object pronouns, forms of *be* and prepositions. (emphasis mine)
>
> <sub>Swan (2006), *Practical English Usage*. Oxford University Press.</sub>